# SQL query to subtract 10% from all items in a single field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to subtract 10% off prices on over 500 products in a single hit, I used an SQL query initially to add 10% for GST purposes, but now I can't work out how to subtract 10% off all items at once.

Help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simple maths, so something like:

```
UPDATE       products
SET          price = price * 0.9
```

Comment: Fantastic, been a long night, after seeing your answer I'm feeling silly. Cheers.

Comment: Of course, if you'd added 10% to something, you'd need to take off 11% to return to the original amount...

Comment: I wouldn't change (UPDATE) the price. I would do a SELECT... PRICE *.9 as 'NonGSTPrice',...